# Prove $\lambda^np_{AB}(\lambda) = \lambda^mp_{BA}(\lambda)$ for non-square $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

**Problem.** 
Suppose $A \in \mathcal{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $B \in \mathcal{M}_{n,m}(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that the characteristic polynomials for the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ satisfy $\lambda^np_{AB}(\lambda) = \lambda^mp_{BA}(\lambda)$.

*Hint:* One way is to use Jordan forms. Alternatively, you might try to use the following block matrices: $P = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda I_m & A \\ B & I_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $Q = \begin{pmatrix} I_m & 0 \\ -B & \lambda I_n \end{pmatrix}$.

**My Question.** 
I have no idea how to use their recommended $P$ and $Q$. Everything I've tried has led absolutely nowhere; no progress at all. I have made some progress using Jordan forms. (Specifically, that $AB$ and $BA$ share the same eigenvalues and that $\dim E_{AB, \lambda} = \dim E_{BA, \lambda}$ for each $\lambda \neq 0$.) So, same factors in $p_{AB}$ and $p_{BA}$, and same geometric multiplicities. But I can't get the final result that the algebraic multiplicities of the nonzero eigenvalues are equal. Instead, I have proved the result using a different strategy, which I have sketched below. Assuming that my proof is correct, I would still like to know how to prove this using the other methods. Any hints?

**My Proof (Sketch).** 
I have showed that for square matrices $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$, $p_{\bar{A}\bar{B}} = p_{\bar{B}\bar{A}}$. So I next assume WLOG that $A$ is wider than tall and $B$ is taller than wide and I augment $A$ and $B$ to square matrices $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ using columns or, respectively, rows of 0's. Then $\bar{A}\bar{B}$ is a block matrix with $AB$ in the upper left and 0 elsewhere, so $p_{\bar{A}\bar{B}} = p_{AB}x^{n-m}$. Then I proved that $\bar{B}\bar{A} = BA$. Thus $p_{AB}x^{n-m} = p_{\bar{A}\bar{B}} = p_{\bar{B}\bar{A}} = p_{BA}$ and the result follows.

Again, hints for the two methods suggested by the problem (or criticisms of my method) would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How did you show equality of the characteristic polynomials for square matrices? However, I think you should apply that for $\bar A=P$ and $\bar B=Q$ or simply something using the determinants.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for the suggestion. To answer your question: I said that for $A$ there exist invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A = P \begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} Q$. Then I let $B = Q^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{21} & B_{22} \end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$. So $AB = P \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{21} & B_{22} \end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$ and $BA = Q^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & 0 \\ B_{21} & 0 \end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$. Then $p_{AB}(\lambda) = \lambda^{n-r} p_{B_{11}}$ and $p_{BA}(\lambda) = \lambda^{n-r} p_{B_11}$.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed (and characteristic zero) and $\text{trace}\big((BA)^k)\big)= \text{trace}\big((AB)^k)\big)$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$ so they have the same non-zero eigenvalues -- the justification typically is Newton's Identities, but there are many other justifications